# Pairs x,y verify equation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, equation

I have to build a program as bellow:

1. User enters 3 Integers: a, b, c
2. User enters one integer n, and then n integers (ascending, and different numbers)
3. Program checks all possible pairs (x,y) (with x!=y) of the numbers entered if verifies the equation a*x^2 + b*y^2 = c and prints all pairs which verifies the equation.

**I done the program as bellow:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int a,b,c,n,i,j;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
cin >> n;
int num[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
   cin >> num[i];
}
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
for (j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
    if(a*num[i]*num[i]+b*num[j]*num[j] == c) {
      cout << "(" << num[i] << "," << num[j] << ")";
    }
    if(a*num[j]*num[j]+b*num[i]*num[i] == c) {
      cout << "(" << num[j] << "," << num[i] << ")";
    }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

I made it by O(nlogn) with two 'for' statements but i know it could be done by O(n).

**NOTE THAT MY PROGRAM WORKS AND I DON'T NEED TO ADD EXPECTED OUTPUT AND MY CURRENT OUTPUT AS YOU SAID IN THE COMMENTS. I ONLY WANT IT TO BE O(N) not O(nlogn) -> I WANT AN OPTIMIZED VERSION OF THE CODE!**

How can I do this?

**Example of running program:** a=1, b=1, c=20
Then n = 5
Then n numbers: 2 3 4 9 18
Program will show all pairs (x,y) which verifies the equation x^2 + y^2 = 20. In this case it shows (2,4)
and (4,2).

Thank you!

Comment: Are these integers?

Comment: Yes! These numbers are Integers

Comment: Then only +-1 satisfies this (*O(n)*)

Comment: Ok. I made it the general case :) thank you

Comment: @JonnyHenly a,b,c are entered at the beginning of program

Comment: @JonnyHenly i am using two loops to verify all pairs x, y. After user enters all numbers then with two loops i make all possible pairs of entered numbers and verify them in the equation. Sorry for my english

Comment: @MMPP Provide a [minimal test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as usual please.

Comment: I edited your tags and removed language specific tags since your question is not language specific. Please don't roll this back again!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ added example. It is ok now?

Comment: @MMPP No, at least not tagging the question c++. Read the link first please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ check now, please. It is ok? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @MMPP [Nope!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e58bf2ce5faaa227)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok edited and added full code

Comment: @MMPP [Still fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0697d27ec32310bd). Also provide input and expected output vs actual output. You might try to take my online IDE example and bang it in shape until your described behavior is actually reproduced. You may consider [Ideone](http://ideone.com/WYMrdD) alternatively, which gives you a bit of easier options regarding the input.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ On the page you provided it says to add the minimum of lines of code, and that is what I did. Anyone who knows c++ as the question was initially tagged with c++ but one removed it, should know to add a basic header on the c++ program like `int main()` or `#include <iostream>` exactly as you added on the first link provided and then forget the header on the second link. I DON'T NEED TO provide input and expected output vs actual output BECAUSE MY CODE WORKS WELL but I WANT ONLY AN OPTIMIZED VERSION OF IT. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 0 based index...

```
Set i=0
Set j=n-1
While i<n or j>=0
    Set sum=a(num[i]^2)+b(num[j^2)
    If sum==c then found pair, and increase i
    If sum<c increase i
    If sum>c decrease j
```

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly this problem solved here: http://lonews.ro/educatie-cultura/22899-rezolvare-admitere-universitatea-bucuresti-2015-pregatire-informatica.html and changed a bit to show the pairs (it originally shows the number of pairs).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a, b, c, n, i=0;
   cout << "a = ";
   cin >> a;
   cout << "b = ";
   cin >> b;
   cout << "c = ";
   cin >> c;
   cout << "n = ";
   cin >> n;

   int s[n];
   for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
       cout << "s[" << i+1 << "] = ";
       cin >> s[i];
   }
   int j=n-1;
   i = 0;
   while(j>=0 || i<n) {
       if(a*s[i]*s[i] + b*s[j]*s[j] == c) {
           cout << "(" << s[i] << "," << s[j] << ") ";
           i++;
       }
       if(a*s[i]*s[i] + b*s[j]*s[j] < c) {
           i++;
       }
       if(a*s[i]*s[i] + b*s[j]*s[j] > c) {
           j--;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```